# Rust-polars Creating a new datetime column from an existing str column

Tags: rust-polars

I read a csv file into a DataFrame. One of the columns is "Date" with strings like 05 Jan 1997. How can I create a new column named datetime and convert items in Date column to datetime format?

NaiveDate::parse_from_str(s, "%d %b %Y") converts the string. But how can I apply this to every item in Date column and put the result in to a new column?

BTW - I am trying this in Rust

```
let df_csv = match read_csv(&file_name) {
        Ok(some) => some,
        Err(err) => {
            eprintln!("Error: {}", err);
            process::exit(1);
        }
    };

// Extract columns Date and Close
let df_csv = df_csv.select(["Date", "Close"]).unwrap();

//Trying to add a datetime column gives an error
let out = df_csv.clone().lazy().select([
        col("Date"),
        col("Date").apply(|s| { 
            Ok(Some(NaiveDate::parse_from_str(&s, "%d %b %Y").unwrap()))} , GetOutput::default()
        )
        .alias("datetime"),
        col("Close")
    ]).collect();
```

The compiler error that I get is

```
   Compiling stock_data_analysis v0.1.0 (/Users/hrishi/Projects/stock_data_analysis)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:89:47
    |
89  | ...     Ok(Some(NaiveDate::parse_from_str(&s, "%d %b %Y").unwr...
    |                 ------------------------- ^^ expected `&str`, found `&Series`
    |                 |
    |                 arguments to this function are incorrect
    |
    = note: expected reference `&str`
               found reference `&polars::prelude::Series`
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:89:21
    |
89  | ...Ok(Some(NaiveDate::parse_from_str(&s, "%d %b %Y").unwrap()))}...
    |       ---- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Series`, found `NaiveDate`
```

apply() gives the entire series but NaiveDate::parse_from_str(...) wants only &str as argument.

My requirement is to call  NaiveDate::parse_from_str(...) on every item in the series col("Date") and create a new column "datetime)

Answer (score 1):

Enable features `lazy`, `string`, and `temporal`, and then

```rust
let df = df![
    "date_str" => ["2 Feb 2023", "not a date"]
]
.unwrap()
.lazy()
.with_column(col("date_str").str().strptime(
    DataType::Date,
    StrptimeOptions {
        format: Some("%d %b %Y".to_owned()),
        strict: false,
        ..Default::default()
    },
    lit("raise"),
));
```

But just to show it can be done with `map` as well:

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let df = df![
        "date_str" => ["2 Feb 2023", "not a date"]
    ]
    .unwrap()
    .lazy()
    .with_column(
        col("date_str")
            .str()
            .strptime(
                DataType::Date,
                StrptimeOptions {
                    format: Some("%d %b %Y".to_owned()),
                    strict: false,
                    ..Default::default()
                },
                lit("raise"),
            )
            .alias("date1"),
    )
    .with_column(
        col("date_str")
            .map(
                |srs| {
                    Ok(Some(
                        DateChunked::from_naive_date_options(
                            "",
                            srs.str()?.into_iter().map(|s| {
                                let s = s?;
                                NaiveDate::parse_from_str(s, "%Y-%m-%d").ok()
                            }),
                        )
                        .into_series(),
                    ))
                },
                GetOutput::from_type(DataType::Date),
            )
            .alias("date2"),
    );

    println!("{:?}", df.collect()?);
    Ok(())
}
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌────────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ date_str   ┆ date1      ┆ date2      │
│ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ str        ┆ date       ┆ date       │
╞════════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ 2023-02-02 ┆ 2023-02-02 ┆ 2023-02-02 │
│ not a date ┆ null       ┆ null       │
└────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you so much @BallpointBen I am still trying to understand how that works. But I confirmed the first method works (non-map that is more concise so that is what I plan to use)